# I can't understand why my testing approach is not working in NestJS

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to test a simple createUser behavior, in this case I want to make the findUnique method from Prisma to return null using jest.fn() but it's not working. If I mock the returned value from jest.fn() function the tests passes.

**user.service.spec.ts**

```js
// [..] omitted imports 

describe('UserService', () => {
  let service: UserService;
  const prismaMock = {
    user: {
      create: jest.fn(() => {
        return { id: 1, name: 'any_name', email: 'any_email@mail.com' };
      }),
      findUnique: jest.fn(),
    },
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UserService,
        { provide: PrismaService, useValue: prismaMock },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
  });

// [...] omitted tests above
  it('should return a new user', async () => {
    const createUserInput = {
      name: 'any_name',
      email: 'any_email@mail.com',
    };

    jest.spyOn(prismaMock.user, 'findUnique').mockReturnValue(null);
    const response = await service.create(createUserInput);

    expect(response).toEqual({
      id: expect.any(Number),
      name: 'any_name',
      email: 'any_email@mail.com',
    });
  });
```

As you can see if I mock the "findUnique" function  as in  `jest.spyOn(prismaMock.user, 'findUnique').mockReturnValue(null);`my tests passes. If I remove the jest.spyOn line of code and make the jest.fn() to return null I get my *ConflictException: User already exists* which is not what I want. Am I missing something from jest.fn() behavior?

**user.service.ts**

```js
// omitted imports 
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const userAlreadyExists = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { email: createUserDto.email },
    });
    
    if (userAlreadyExists) {
      throw new ConflictException('User already exists');
    }

    const createdUser = this.prisma.user.create({ data: createUserDto });
    return createdUser;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function fn(): Mock; jest.fn() returns Mock function. You have to mock the implementation to get the desired output.

In your case, you can try mocking like this  findUnique: jest.fn(() => null)

Comment: I've tried this approach and it doesn't work. When I do it I get my ConflictException :/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).